# gRPC - request response performance

Tags: c#, grpc

[gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/) 1.1.0 C# .NET 4.6 Windows 7 / Windows 10

I have just tested out the performance of gRPC in C# and am puzzled about its performance between computers.  Small messages take a consistent 200ms send/reply time, and larger messages (around 1500 characters) are sub-millisecond.  See client/server code below.  Is there additional configuration needed to handle small messages?

My test is following the getting started guide here: http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html

In a nutshell, there is a `Greeter` service with a `SayHello` endpoint accepting `HelloRequest` and responds with a `HelloResponse`.

```
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

**Client**

Again, nearly the same as the sample.  Notice the `stringLength` variable.  When it is set to a value between 1-1200(ish), the time to receive a response is consistently 200ms

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var channel = new Channel("192.168.82.254", 50051, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

        var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
        var stringLength = 1500;
        for (var x = 0; x < 50; x++)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var req = new HelloRequest { Name = new String('x', stringLength) };
            var reply = client.SayHello(req);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Greeting: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        }           
        Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}
```

**Server**

Pretty simple, handles the request and responds back.  Verbatim from the sample.

```
const int Port = 50051;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Server server = new Server
    {
        Services = { Greeter.BindService(new GreeterImpl()) },
        Ports = { new ServerPort("192.168.82.254", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
    };
    server.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Greeter server listening on port " + Port);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
}

class GreeterImpl : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
    // Server side handler of the SayHello RPC
    public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply { Message = "Hello " + request.Name });
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try to measure *just* the gRPC time as far as possible: take the request creation out of the loop, and likewise time the whole loop rather than each iteration. Normal benchmarking things, basically. (It doesn't explain anything you've seen so far, but it's a good idea to do that sort of thing anyway...)

Comment: Thx for reply, tried that.  Same loop, just calling `SayHello(req)` 50 times.  Total duration 10243 ms ~= 204ms.  Seems like a magic number.

Comment: I wonder whether [Nagle's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) is to blame...

Comment: No additional configuration is needed for small messages, things should just work. The numbers you measure should be comparable with the "official" public benchmarks we run for gRPC continously. See [1.1.x dashboard](http://performance-dot-grpc-testing.appspot.com/explore?dashboard=5636470266134528), which indicates your latency can be as low as 250micros for unary ping pong on linux.

Comment: More details about what platform you are running on would be useful. In the past, I wasn't able to reproduce https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8806 on my windows machine, but it was happening on GCE.

Comment: My tests were on windows 7 / windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [1.1.x dashboard](http://performance-dot-grpc-testing.appspot.com/explore?dashboard=5636470266134528) seems to indicate that version 1.1.0 still has a problem with ping-pong timing on Windows - https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8806. That seems to be fixed on current master and in v1.2.x. Please use the 1.2.0-pre1 nugets to verify (we're really close to 1.2.0 release now, so the official 1.2.0 packages will follow pretty soon - in the meantime, having a confirmation from you would be very useful).

The [master dashboard](http://performance-dot-grpc-testing.appspot.com/explore?dashboard=5652536396611584)

Comment: Just installed 1.2.0-pre1 nuget and the behavior has changed.  A small message (1 character) is now round tripped sub-millisecond, however in my loop of 50 attempts, a few messages are still taking ~200ms round trip.

Comment: to follow up on my results...  Small messages (e.g. 10 char string ping-pong) no longer exhibit the 200ms delay **however** every few messages out of the 50 sent **do** exhibit a 200ms delay.  The same holds true for larger messages (10,000) char string ping-pong.  Every few messages will be 200ms whereas the rest are sub-millisecond.  I really want to adopt this library but I require consistent timing between processes over the network.

Comment: Please file an issue directly at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/new and include as much information about your platform & environment as possible and we will look into that.